# Is there any way to speed up a complex query with 3x UNION All on the same large table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, case, union, union-all

I am working on optimizing a procedure, currently it takes a little more than 23 minutes to execute from SQL. I have tried re-indexing my tables and it showed no signs of improvement.

I have not been able to figure out a way to us a cross apply or UNPIVOT for this to work right.

Is there anything i could do to improve the speed of this procedure?

```
    @ClientId int,
    @FormParentId int = NULL,
    @FormQueryMode varchar(20) = 'changelog'
declare
    @ClientId int,
    @FormParentId INT,
    @FormQueryMode varchar(20)

select
        @ClientId = 11,
        @FormParentId = 277719,
        @FormQueryMode = NULL

DROP TABLE #History
*/
    CREATE TABLE #History
    (
        FormHistRecId bigint IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        FormParentId int,
        EffDate datetime,
        Updated datetime NULL,
        Change varchar(50),
        VersionNote varchar(1000),
        VersionUserId varchar(50)
    )

    INSERT INTO #History (FormParentId, EffDate, Updated, Change, VersionNote, VersionUserId)
    SELECT ParentId, EffDate, Updated, Change, VersionNote, VersionUserId
    FROM (
        SELECT f.ClientId, CASE WHEN f.MainFormId IS NULL THEN f.ParentId ELSE (SELECT ParentId FROM Forms WHERE FormId=f.MainFormId) END AS ParentId, f.EffDate, f.Updated, 'Forms' as Change, 
            f.VersionNote, f.VersionUserId
        FROM Forms f
        WHERE Status IN (0,1,2) --negatives are 'temporary', and should be ignored if they aren't already cleaned out
        UNION ALL/*
        SELECT f.ClientId, (SELECT ParentId FROM Forms WHERE FormId=f.MainFormId) AS ParentId, f.EffDate, f.Updated, 'Attachment_Forms' as Change, 
            f.VersionNote, f.VersionUserId
        FROM Forms f
        WHERE Status IN (0,1,2) --negatives are 'temporary', and should be ignored if they aren't already cleaned out
        UNION ALL*/
        SELECT f.ClientId, CASE WHEN f.MainFormId IS NULL THEN f.ParentId ELSE (SELECT ParentId FROM Forms WHERE FormId=f.MainFormId) END, h.EffDate, h.Updated, 'Holders' as Change, 'Holder Updated' as VersionNote, h.VersionUserId
        FROM Forms f
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Forms f_exp ON f_exp.FormId=(
            SELECT TOP 1 FormId
            FROM Forms 
            WHERE ParentId=f.ParentId 
            AND ( EffDate > f.EffDate OR (EffDate=f.EffDate AND Updated > f.Updated))
            ORDER BY EffDate ASC, Updated ASC
        )
        --check for holder updates within the span this Forms record's selection implies
        INNER JOIN Holders h ON h.ParentId=f.HolderParentId
                AND h.EffDate >= f.EffDate --must be effective after-or-with the form
                AND h.EffDate >= f.Updated --must be entered after-or-with the form
                AND (f_exp.FormId IS NULL OR h.EffDate < f_exp.EffDate) --must be effective before next form becomes effective
                AND (f_exp.FormId IS NULL OR h.EffDate < f_exp.Updated) --must be entered before next form is entered
        UNION ALL
        SELECT f.ClientId, CASE WHEN f.MainFormId IS NULL THEN f.ParentId ELSE (SELECT ParentId FROM Forms WHERE FormId=f.MainFormId) END, ct.Updated as EffDate, NULL AS Updated, 'ClientTemplates' as Change
            ,ct.VersionNote, ct.VersionUserId
        FROM Forms f
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Forms f_exp ON f_exp.FormId=(
            SELECT TOP 1 FormId
            FROM Forms 
            WHERE ParentId=f.ParentId 
            AND ( EffDate > f.EffDate OR (EffDate=f.EffDate AND Updated > f.Updated))
            ORDER BY EffDate ASC, Updated ASC
        )
        INNER JOIN ClientTemplates ct ON ct.ParentId=f.TemplateParentId
                AND ct.Updated >= f.EffDate
                --AND ct.Updated >= f.Updated
                AND (f_exp.FormId IS NULL OR ct.Updated < f_exp.EffDate)
                --AND (f_exp.FormId IS NULL OR ct.Updated < f_exp.Updated)
        UNION ALL
        SELECT f.ClientId, CASE WHEN f.MainFormId IS NULL THEN f.ParentId ELSE (SELECT ParentId FROM Forms WHERE FormId=f.MainFormId) END, mt.Updated as EffDate, NULL AS Updated, 'MasterTemplates' as Change
            ,mt.VersionNote, mt.VersionUserId
        FROM Forms f
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Forms f_exp ON f_exp.FormId=(
            SELECT TOP 1 FormId
            FROM Forms 
            WHERE ParentId=f.ParentId 
            AND ( EffDate > f.EffDate OR (EffDate=f.EffDate AND Updated > f.Updated))
            ORDER BY EffDate ASC, Updated ASC
        )
        INNER JOIN ClientTemplates ct ON ct.ParentId=f.TemplateParentId
                AND ct.Updated >= f.EffDate
                --AND ct.Updated >= f.Updated
                AND (f_exp.FormId IS NULL OR ct.Updated < f_exp.EffDate)
                --AND (f_exp.FormId IS NULL OR ct.Updated < f_exp.Updated)
        LEFT OUTER JOIN ClientTemplates ct_exp ON ct_exp.TemplateId=(
            SELECT TOP 1 TemplateId
            FROM ClientTemplates 
            WHERE ParentId=ct.ParentId 
            AND Updated > ct.Updated    --(no eff date)
            ORDER BY Updated ASC
        )
        INNER JOIN MasterTemplates mt ON mt.ParentId=ct.MasterParentId
                AND mt.Updated >= ct.Updated
                --AND mt.Updated >= ct.Updated
                AND (ct_exp.TemplateId IS NULL OR mt.Updated < ct_exp.Updated)
        UNION ALL
        SELECT (SELECT TOP 1 ClientId FROM Forms WHERE ParentId=ctblsel.FormParentId), 
            (SELECT
            CASE WHEN f.MainFormId IS NULL THEN f.ParentId ELSE (SELECT ParentId FROM Forms WHERE FormId=f.MainFormId) END
            FROM Forms f WHERE FormId=(
                SELECT TOP 1 FormId
                FROM Forms
                WHERE ParentId=ctblsel.FormParentId
                AND ( EffDate > ctblsel.EffDate OR (EffDate=ctblsel.EffDate AND Updated > ctblsel.Updated))
                ORDER BY EffDate DESC, Updated DESC
                ) 
            )AS FormParentId,
            --ctblsel.FormParentId, 
ctblsel.EffDate, ctblsel.Updated, 'CTblEntrySelection' as Change
            ,'Client Table Entry Selected' as VersionNote, ctblsel.VersionUserId
        FROM CTblEntrySelection ctblsel
    ) dt
    WHERE ClientId=@ClientId
    AND (@FormParentId IS NULL OR ParentId=@FormParentId)

    DECLARE CTblCur CURSOR FOR
    SELECT ClientTableId
    FROM ClientTables
    WHERE ClientId=@ClientId
    OPEN CTblCur
    DECLARE @ClientTableId int
    DECLARE @q nvarchar(MAX), @p nvarchar(100), @tblname nvarchar(50)
    SET @p =
'@ClientId int,
@FormParentId int,
@ClientTableId int'
    FETCH NEXT FROM CTblCur INTO @ClientTableId
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @tblname = '[ClientTable_'+CONVERT(nvarchar,@ClientTableId)+']'
        SET @q = 
'INSERT INTO #History (FormParentId, EffDate, Updated, Change, VersionNote, VersionUserId)
SELECT ctblsel.FormParentId, ctbl.Updated as EffDate, NULL AS Updated, ''ClientTable'' as Change
    ,ctbl.VersionNote, ctbl.VersionUserId
FROM CTblEntrySelection ctblsel
LEFT OUTER JOIN CTblEntrySelection ctblsel_exp ON ctblsel_exp.RecId = (
        SELECT TOP 1 RecId
        FROM CTblEntrySelection
        WHERE FormParentId=ctblsel.FormParentId
        AND ClientTableId=ctblsel.ClientTableId
        AND ( EffDate > ctblsel.EffDate OR (EffDate=ctblsel.EffDate AND Updated > ctblsel.Updated))
        ORDER BY EffDate ASC, Updated ASC
)
INNER JOIN '+@tblname+' ctbl ON ctbl.ParentId=ctblsel.CTblEntryParentId
        AND ctbl.Updated >= ctblsel.EffDate --must be effective after-or-with the form
        --AND ctbl.Updated >= ctblsel.Updated --must be entered after-or-with the form
        AND (ctblsel_exp.RecId IS NULL OR ctbl.Updated < ctblsel_exp.EffDate) --must be effective before next form becomes effective
        --AND (ctblsel_exp.RecId IS NULL OR ctbl.Updated < ctblsel_exp.Updated) --must be entered before next form is entered
WHERE (SELECT TOP 1 ClientId FROM Forms WHERE ParentId=ctblsel.FormParentId)=@ClientId
AND ctblsel.ClientTableId=@ClientTableId'
        IF @FormParentId IS NOT NULL
            SET @q = @q + '
AND ctblsel.FormParentId=@FormParentId'
print @q
        EXEC sp_ExecuteSql @q, @p, @ClientId, @FormParentId, @ClientTableId
        FETCH NEXT FROM CTblCur INTO @ClientTableId
    END
    CLOSE CTblCur
    DEALLOCATE CTblCur

    IF @FormQueryMode = 'issuancelog'
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO #History (FormParentId, EffDate, Updated, Change, VersionNote, VersionUserId)
        SELECT l.FormParentId, l.EffDate, l.Updated, 'Issuance', h.VersionNote, l.UserId
        FROM FormIssuanceLog l
        LEFT OUTER JOIN #History h ON h.FormHistRecId=(
            SELECT TOP 1 FormHistRecId
            FROM #History
            WHERE FormParentId=l.FormParentId
            AND EffDate <= l.EffDate
            AND COALESCE(Updated,EffDate) <= l.Updated --if #history's Updated is null, means it's a change that cannot be anachronistic; updated = effective.
            ORDER BY EffDate DESC, Updated DESC
        )
        WHERE (
            (@FormParentId IS NOT NULL AND l.FormParentId=@FormParentId)
            OR
            (@FormParentId IS NULL AND l.FormParentId IN ( SELECT ParentId FROM Forms WHERE ClientId=@ClientId ))
        )
        AND l.ConfirmIssued=1

        DELETE FROM #History WHERE Change<>'Issuance'
    END

    SELECT *,
        LastName + ', ' + FirstName + ' (' + Username + ')' as VersionAuthor
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            'Courier' FormType,
            dt2.FormParentId,
            NULL as LegacyFormId,
            dt2.EffDate,
            dt2.Updated,
            dt2.Change,
            dt2.VersionNote,
            dt2.VersionUserId
            ,Forms.FormId, ClientTemplates.Name as CTName, Users.FirstName, Users.LastName, Users.Username
            ,'Courier_'+CONVERT(nvarchar,dt2.FormParentId)+'_'+CONVERT(nvarchar,dt2.EffDate,127)+COALESCE('_'+CONVERT(nvarchar,dt2.Updated,127),'') as PK
            ,CASE Change
                WHEN 'MasterTemplates' THEN 'Master Form (blank PDF)'
                WHEN 'ClientTemplates' THEN 'Template'
                WHEN 'ClientTable' THEN 'Client Table'
                WHEN 'Forms' THEN 'Form'
                WHEN 'Holders' THEN 'Holder Address Record'
                WHEN 'CTblEntrySelection' THEN 'Client Table Selection'
                WHEN 'Issuance' THEN 'Form Issuance'
                ELSE '-----'
            END ChangeText
            ,'pg_IssuanceLogPrompt' as Interface
            ,CASE @FormQueryMode WHEN 'issuancelog' THEN 'ShowHistForm_IssMode' ELSE 'ShowHistForm' END as Command
            ,CONVERT(varchar(50),dt2.FormParentId) as Param1
            ,CONVERT(varchar(50),dt2.EffDate,126) Param2
            ,CONVERT(varchar(50),dt2.Updated,126) Param3
            ,'Courier.frm' AS HTTPTarget
            ,Forms.Status FormStatus
            ,ie.Name AS EditionName
        FROM (
            SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY FormParentId, EffDate, Updated ORDER BY ChangeDominance ASC ) rn
            FROM (
                SELECT *,
                    CASE Change 
                        WHEN 'MasterTemplates' THEN 1
                        WHEN 'ClientTemplates' THEN 2
                        WHEN 'ClientTable' THEN 3
                        WHEN 'Forms' THEN 4
                        WHEN 'Holders' THEN 5
                        WHEN 'CTblEntrySelection' THEN 6
                        ELSE 99
                    END as ChangeDominance  --largely applies to change log; issuance log will get 99, but it only has one value anyway
                FROM #History
            ) dt
        ) dt2
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Forms ON Forms.FormId=(
            SELECT TOP 1 FormId
            FROM Forms
            WHERE ParentId=dt2.FormParentId
            AND EffDate <= dt2.EffDate
            AND Updated <= COALESCE(dt2.Updated, dt2.Updated) --if #history's Updated is null, means it's a change that cannot be anachronistic; updated = effective.
            AND [Status] >= 0
            ORDER BY EffDate DESC, Updated DESC
        )
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Users ON Users.UserId=dt2.VersionUserId
        LEFT OUTER JOIN ClientTemplates ON ClientTemplates.TemplateId=(
            SELECT TOP 1 TemplateId
            FROM ClientTemplates
            WHERE ParentId=Forms.TemplateParentId
            AND Updated <= dt2.EffDate
            --AND Updated <= dt2.Updated
            ORDER BY Updated DESC
        )
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.IssuanceEditions ie ON ie.EditionId=(
            SELECT TOP 1 EditionId
            FROM dbo.IssuanceEditions ie2
            WHERE ie2.ClientId=(SELECT DISTINCT ClientId FROM dbo.Forms WHERE ParentId=dt2.FormParentId)
            AND ie2.Updated <= dt2.EffDate
            ORDER BY ie2.Updated DESC
        )           
        WHERE rn=1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 
            'LegacyPDF' as FormType,
            NULL as FormParentId,
            LegacyFormId,
            EffDate,
            NULL as Updated,
            'Imported File' as Change,
            HistDescription as VersionNote,
            NULL as VersionUserId
            ,NULL as FormId, NULL as CTName, NULL as FirstName, NULL as LastName, NULL as Username
            ,'LegacyPDF_'+CONVERT(nvarchar,LegacyFormId) as PK
            ,'Imported File' as ChangeText
            ,'ShowLegacyForm' as Interface
            ,'' as Command
            ,CONVERT(varchar(50),LegacyFormId) as Param1
            ,NULL Param2
            ,NULL Param3
            ,'Courier.dwnl' AS HTTPTarget
            ,NULL FormStatus
            ,NULL EditionName
        FROM LegacyForms
        WHERE ClientId=@ClientId
        AND (@FormParentId IS NULL OR FormParentId=@FormParentId)
    ) dt
    ORDER BY EffDate DESC, Updated DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

The cursor jumps out as something you may want to look at eliminating. This is such a large query with so many pieces its almost impossible to see where, and if, it can be improved.

Look at the query plans generated by the batch and probably one, or two queries will take up 80% if the batch and those should be examined very carefully. I would predict that most of the time is spent on the sp_executesql statement and that, if possible should be changed to a join that SQL Server could optimize.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I will try that. This is an old query that use to run fine for a web program but now is causing many issues to occur.

Comment: Whats probably happened (guessing wildly here...) that the number of clients has increased so the cursor is executing many more times.....

Comment: that is correct. There are over 3,000 client tables now. I had to start and create a new database just for one client to continue to run the program.

Comment: If you want to do relational operations you probably want one table with an extra column for clientid. Its going to take some rewriting of code but over the medium and long term your life will be much, much more functional.